# Problems in trying to move my Cocos2d 2.0 project on a MacBook with an older Xcode installed (and Cocos2d v1)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.2, xcode4.3

Ahh.. help! I have a flight in 10 hours and have to move my project from my iMac running Lion to a friend's MacBook Pro (running a 10.6.8 MacOSX). I had already an account made 6 months ago and had installed XCode 4.2 on it.

So now I copied the Project folder from my iMac to the MacBook pro and then tried to run. No success. I then copied as well the Cococs2D v2 library (previously I had only the v1 in that Mac) but no success. Unfortunately I am not sure if copying and extracting is enough and hence I run also "install templates". But I still get the following problem:

[image: problem]

It seems related to the absence of the Foundation class but I have no idea on how to solve this.. any help??

EDIT: I tried to create a brand new project on the "old" MacBook Pro with the "old" XCode 4.2 and it doesn't work.. ahh.. why? This time it fails to find the UIKit.h file.

I think it got completely messed up.. probably I should try to download a new XCode and start from scratch.. but then I will have to reconfigure also the developer certificates on it I think.

Here is the new error..

[image]

Comment: check the build paths and stuff like that for your project. My advice, create a new project on the old laptop, and compare the settings to see where the changes are. Worst case scenario, create a new project on the old laptop and manually add all your classes and assets to that new project, till it is functionally ther same as the old one. Wish i could help more, and good luck.

Comment: Yep, thanks. I tried to create a brand new project (Both Cocos2d 2 and iOS) and I get an error in the Prefix.phc file saying that UIKit/UIkit.h is not found.. basically, I can't even get to run a simple new project on my old mac now.. mmhh weird..

Comment: A couple of things to try (I don't know anything about Cocos2D so is a guess)...  Are the right frameworks included in the project?  Try deleting the derived data (through the organizer) and do a clean (Product -> Clean)?

Comment: I tried product clean but did not work. I am not sure how to check if the right frameworks are included in the project. Would you be able to guide me on this? Is there any tutorial?

Comment: Posted as answer so I could include an image.

Comment: Is development with Mac OS X 10.6 and Xcode 4.2 even supported today? Perhaps it's as simple as upgrading OS and/or Xcode. In any case, try reinstalling Xcode. If even new templates from Apple fail to function, something is definitely broken.

Answer (score 0):

Image below shows where you can see the frameworks in your project.  Add a framework using the plus (+) button.

[image]

From the errors in your pch file, looks like you need at least the Foundation.framework and UIKit.framework.